# Scrapy shell returning None as a response

Tags: python, python-requests, scrapy

I'm trying to debug a scrape.

```py
scrapy shell
>>>fetch("https://www.mottmac.com/")
>>>print (response)
None
```

vs when I use requests:

```py
>>>import requests

>>>resp = requests.get("https://www.mottmac.com/")
>>>print (resp)
<Response [200]>
```

Why is this the case?

Comment: What does the console return after the `fetch` command? What version of python and scrapy are you running? Is this ipython?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. I have a broad crawl scraper set up with `COOKIES_ENABLED = FALSE` set up in my settings. The website required cookies so I changed it to be: `COOKIES_ENABLED = True`.

I figured this out by launching a scrapy shell outside of my project and fetching the URL. It worked. So I launched the shell both outside and inside the project then in the interactive shell I entered the command `settings` then copied and pasted the response into notepad++. I compared the differences and worked out cookies were the problem.